# Creating an Association from a User Token

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have an API that authenticates with a bearer token. I would like to decode the token into a `user_id`, look up a user, and add that user to a project that they're creating in a post request.

I have everything working properly in the project context using a hardcoded user like so:

```
def changeset(%Project{} = project, attrs) do
    project
    |> cast(attrs, [:name, :url])
    |> validate_required([:name, :url])
    |> put_assoc(:users, [get_user])
  end

  defp get_user do
    Repo.one(from x in User, order_by: [desc: x.id], limit: 1)
  end
```

I can also decode the token in the controller to get a `user_id`:

```
def create(conn, %{"project" => project_params}) do
    user_id = SomeFunction.gives.me.an.id
    with {:ok, %Project{} = project} <- Projects.create_project(project_params) do
      conn
      |> put_status(:created)
      |> put_resp_header("location", project_path(conn, :show, project))
      |> render("show.json", project: project)
    end
  end
```

And, the `create_project` function looks like this:

```
def create_project(attrs \\ %{}) do
    %Project{}
    |> Project.changeset(attrs)
    |> Repo.insert()
  end
```

But, what's the best way to pass the `user_id` from the controller to the context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add a parameter to the context function**

`Projects.create_project(user_id, project_params)`

While one could argue that `user_id` should be merged into the `project_params` I think it should get its own parameter.

It is probable that other context functions will also require the current user. Think of `Project.list_projects(user_id)` that will only return the projects the user is allowed to see or `Project.destroy_project(user_id, project_id)` that will check if the user is allowed to destroy that project.

**Assign the `user_id` to your `conn`**

When the `user_id` is part of most requests you can assign it to your `conn` in your router using [Plug.Conn#assign/3](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#assign/3). In your controllers you can then use `conn.assigns.user_id`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! If I add it as a parameter to the context function, how would I then create the association? I cannot easily call `put_assoc(:users, [user])` since the schema isn't in the context. And, I tried `Map.put` to add it to the `attrs` being sent to the `changeset`, but it doesn't seem to be adding it as a param. Do you have any insights into that part?

Comment: I added `|> Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(:users, user)` in the `create_context` function and it works well enough. I'm guessing that's the best way to do it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm glad you solved it. You could also move that line to a new function in your model and call it from your context like `|> Project.set_users([user_id])`